# Adding to ArrayList constructor

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, constructor, addition

I got a question regarding ArrayLists, I can't seem to wrap my head around the concept. Basically I'm making an ArrayList without the main method in the constructor. I need to add multiple 'users' to my ArrayList, just I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

```
package lab4;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserGroupz{

private ArrayList<User> users;

    public UserGroupz(){
        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

        //MY PROBLEM IS IN THIS METHOD BELOW!
    public void addSampleData(User user){
        users.add(user);
    }



    public int numberOfUsers(){
        return users.size();
    }

    public void printUsernames(int userNumber){
        if(userNumber < 0){ 
        }
        else if(userNumber < numberOfUsers()){
            System.out.println(users.get(3));
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    public void listUsers(){
        for(User allUsers : users){   
            System.out.println(allUsers);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: Is this what you're talking about?:  Add another constructor public UserGroupz(User[] usersToAdd).  Inside the constructor, initialize your users ArrayList, then loop through usersToAdd, adding all of them to users.  Or if you want to add more after UserGroupz is defined, just write a method addUsers(User[] usersToAdd).

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is calling the `addSampleData()` repeatedly to add users and instead you want to add multiple users in one go, then you can use the `ArrayList#addAll()` method which will add all the elements from another collection into your `ArrayList`.

> public boolean addAll(Collection c)
>
> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of
>   this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified
>   collection's Iterator. The behavior of this operation is undefined if
>   the specified collection is modified while the operation is in
>   progress. (This implies that the behavior of this call is undefined if
>   the specified collection is this list, and this list is nonempty.)

To do this, you will collate all the users into another `ArrayList` and then pass that as the argument to `addSampleData()` which calls `addAll` method of your main `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

in the main,you create a UserGroupz  object ,

```
   UserGroupz ugz = new UserGroupz();
   ugz.addSampleData(user);
   ugz.listUsers();
```